# Convert a file into a matrix, replace each character with a number in Python

Tags: file, python-2.7, matrix, replace

Following instructions to solve a maze problem, I need to read from a file and then convert it into a matrix. Once this is done I need to replace every "#" (represents a wall) with -1, every " " (representing a corridor) with 0 and every "M" (represents a minotaur) with -2. I've managed to convert the file into a matrix but the latter half concerning the replace I am running into problems.

I am a beginner and have only been learning python for a couple months now(hence why my following code is probably painful to read). Thanks so much for any help!

The file being read contains the following:

```
###########
      # # #
# ### # # #
# #   # # #
# ##### # #
#       # #
# ####### #
# #       #
# ####### #
#          
###########
```

Here is my code:

```
def loadmaze(filename):
    f = open(filename)
    lines = f.readlines()
    COR = "0"
    WALL = "-1"
    MINO = "2"
    new_maze = []
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        lines[i] = "*" + lines[i]
        lines[i] = lines[i].strip("*").strip("\n")
        new_maze.append(lines[i])
    x = new_maze
    con_maze = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        z = list(x[i])
        con_maze.append(z)
    for i in range(len(con_maze)):
        for j in range(len(con_maze[i])):
            con_maze[i][j].replace("'#'", COR)
            con_maze[i][j].replace(" ", WALL)
            con_maze[i][j].replace("M", MINO)

    return con_maze

print loadmaze("maze.txt")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation.

Comment: I've rolled back the question to its original form; please don't destroy your own questions, as that destroys whatever (marginal) utility the question and answer might have for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
from pprint import pprint

def loadmaze(filename):

    maze = []

    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            with_delimiters = ''
            for i,ch in enumerate(line):
                with_delimiters += 'S' + ch
            line = with_delimiters

            inchars = '# M'
            outchars = ['-1','0','-2']
            for i,ch in enumerate(inchars):
                line = line.replace(ch,outchars[i])
                line = line.replace('\n','')

            maze_col = line.split('S')
            for i in maze_col:  
                if i == '':
                    maze_col.remove(i)
            maze.append(map(int,maze_col))

    return maze


pprint (loadmaze('maze.txt'))
```

output:

```
[[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1],
 [-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1],
 [-1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1],
 [-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 0, -1],
 [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1],
 [-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1],
 [-1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1],
 [-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1],
 [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]
```